# Combine Rows output for multiple column checks

Tags: plsql, listagg

I want to combine multiple rows into single one based on multiple column checks.
[image]

Only if all the remaining columns match then Program_Type should get merged as comma separated.

I tried using listagg but I am unable to achieve it . I also tried using connect by but still not able to check all the conditions.

Any help on same.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
select 
listagg(PROGRAM_TYPE,',')
within group ( order by PROGRAM_TYPE DESC ) as PROG_GROUP
from emp
```

**Output:**

```
XYZ,MNO
```

Further if you want to have all columns in a single query

```
With PROGRAM1_TYPE 
as (
select distinct id,prog_type
from
(
select id,listagg(PROGRAM_TYPE,',') within group ( order by PROGRAM_TYPE DESC ) 
over (partition by id ) prog_type
from emp
)
)select distinct e.id,e.name,prog_type PROGRAM_TYPE,
e.MNAME,e.type --add remaining columns here
from  PROGRAM1_TYPE p,emp e 
where p.id=e.id
```

O/p -Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one or two big tables which you need to simplify then you could easily do this in a few steps

1. Sort by any of the columns which need to be the same (e.g ID).
2. In an extra column write a function to detect which rows are the same as the ones below and which are not - something along the lines of for row 3 - IF(AND(A3=A4, B3=B4), "same","last").
3. In another column add an equation to concatenate the program types if the rows are the same  eg.   =IF(F3="last",C4,G3&", "&C4)
4. Once the values are in place do a copy and "paste results" on the two columns (so you have the values not the equations)
5. Sort on the same/last column, keeping the "last" rows and discard the "same"

of course if you need to do this repeatedly then this is a cumbersome solution and you probably should use a macro or a database program.